# VBA doesnt run when cell value changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get this macro run automatically when a value in the target cell changes but it's not working, searched solutions for hours but am still hitting the wall, sorry I am new to VBA. Really appreciate it if any kind soul could help.

```
My code is below:

Sub Hide_Row()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = Sheets("PL").Range("F32:F35,F41:F44,F50:F53,F59:F62")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Sheets("PL").Range("E30")
        If MyRange.Value = "0" Then
            Sheets("PL").Rows("30:31").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets("PL").Rows("30:31").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Set MyRange = Sheets("PL").Range("E39")
        If MyRange.Value = "0" Then
            Sheets("PL").Rows("39:40").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets("PL").Rows("39:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Set MyRange = Sheets("PL").Range("E48")
        If MyRange.Value = "0" Then
            Sheets("PL").Rows("48:49").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets("PL").Rows("48:49").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It must be called `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` and placed in "PL" sheet's module.

Comment: How are the values changing - is someone editing the value directly, or is it as the result of a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are being edited directly then you can do something like this (in the code module of the "PL" worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Me.Range("F32:F35,F41:F44,F50:F53,F59:F62").Cells
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Value = 0)
    Next
    For Each cell In Me.Range("E30,E39,E48").Cells
        cell.Resize(2, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Value = 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

...but once the zero values are entered, it's difficult to see how you'd then unhide the rows...

If cell values are changing because of formula recalculation then you need to look at the `Worksheet_Calculate` event